# undefined reference in c program

Tags: c, mongodb, reference, linker, undefined

I wrote a set of c files where functions in those files are used in a main C file. I have written header files and also included them in the main c file.

It was working fine before. Then, I had to integrate logic to access mongodb from this program. So i had to set `C_INCLUDE_PATH` to refer `mongoc.h` and `bson.h`, etc. I set it as follows:

```
sanuri@ubuntu:~/Desktop/December/SMS_manager$ C_INCLUDE_PATH=.:/usr/local/include:/home/sanuri/Desktop/ETSP/mongo-c-driver-0.98.0/src/mongoc:/home/sanuri/Desktop/ETSP/mongo-c-driver-0.98.0/src/libbson/src/bson
sanuri@ubuntu:~/Desktop/December/SMS_manager$ export C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Now `mongoc.h` and `bson.h` are recognized. But my own functions in other C files I wrote are not recognized which are in the same directory as the main C file. I get following errors:

```
/tmp/ccg5BR9V.o: In function `getDetails':
ReceiveSMS.c:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to `str_split'
ReceiveSMS.c:(.text+0x15c): undefined reference to `trimwhitespace'
/tmp/ccg5BR9V.o: In function `getMessageDetails':
ReceiveSMS.c:(.text+0xa80): undefined reference to `authenticate'
/tmp/ccg5BR9V.o: In function `main':
ReceiveSMS.c:(.text+0xbc1): undefined reference to `getNoOfCPUs'
ReceiveSMS.c:(.text+0xbca): undefined reference to `configure'
```

These are functions in three C files I wrote. Please give me a solution for this. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: undefined reference is a Linker issue you're not linking the library that defines those symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry your question has only partial info, you have not produced how you are compiling/linking.

there are many ways of solving this, I try to put some:
one:
For gcc you can provide  -I -L -l options

```
-I include directory path i.e. headers
-L library path say libc.so, libc.a etc.,
-l for library name say -lmy for saying use/link libmy.* library
ex: 
a. gcc -o myapp myapp.c -I./include -L./lib -lmy
b. gcc -o myapp myapp.c -I./include ./lib/libmy.a
```

two:
In linux environ gcc accepts flags like CFLAGS, LDFLAGS 
you can use these flags in your Makefile
$ cat Makefile

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -I./include
LDFLAGS=-lmy -L./lib 

SOURCE=main.c

myapp: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCE) -o myapp $(LDFLAGS)
```

Hope you learn something, thanks for opportunity to teach.